# TemplateSyntaxError : Could not parse the remainder: '(ticket.status' from '(ticket.status'

Tags: python, django, django-templates, web-development-server

when i use this condition it gives an syntax error
like this

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /developers/dev_pendings/
Could not parse the remainder: '(ticket.status' from '(ticket.status'

Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/developers/dev_pendings/Django 
Version:        4.2.6
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxErrorException 
Value:          Could not parse the remainder: '(ticket.status' from '(ticket.status'
Exception Location: C:\Users\x\Desktop\lspok\vnv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py, line 703, in init
Raised during:  Developers.views.devPendingsDashboardPython 
Executable:     C:\Users\x\Desktop\lspok\vnv\scripts\python.exePython 
Version:        3.11.3
Python Path:    ['C:\Users\x\Desktop\lspok\pokeus',
                 'C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python311.zip',
                 'C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\DLLs',
                 'C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib',
                 'C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311',
                 'C:\Users\x\Desktop\lspok\vnv',
                 'C:\Users\x\Desktop\lspok\vnv\Lib\site-packages'
                 ]
Server time:    Wed, 18 Oct 2023 11:44:14 +0530'
```

The code i used like this :

```
{% elif (ticket.status == 'DA' or ticket.status == "CD" ) and  ticket.tester_id != '' %}
```

Why this happening, isn't it right way in Django?

I just want evaluate this condition correctly

Comment: [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#if) clearly say that _Use of actual parentheses in the if tag is invalid syntax. If you need them to indicate precedence, you should use nested if tags._